# Impersonate the whole process, not just a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, impersonation, windows-identity

I'm using [SimpleImpersonation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation/) package, which does dirty work around some extern functions, for example

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);
```

I'm using it like this:

```
using (var imp = Impersonation.LogonUser(domain, user, password, LogonType.Interactive))
{
    // another user
}
//me again
```

The problem is that this method impersonates user only for current thread, while I need to perform actions under another credentials from all threads in my application. How to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for here. You have successfully impersonated a section of code, then you ask "for this other section of code that I dont show you, how do I impersonate that?"

Comment: Don't focus on my exact code, just tell me, how to impersonate the whole process, but not the single thread. In other words, how to use once impersonated credentials in every thread of an application?

Comment: create other threads in impersonated thread :)

Comment: @EZI that is too difficult in my project, even changing each worker's thread to impersonate is overkill. Also I need to change user frequently, not only at application startup

Comment: Sounds like you need to refactor.

Comment: @paqogomez Ofcource I need. Every program needs it, to some extent. But we are programmers to release products, not for coding, right?